# How can one implement in Java the same as JavaScript String.replace(RegEx, function)?

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I would like to do some simple String replace with a regular expression in Java, but the replace value is not static and I would like it to be dynamic like it happens on JavaScript.

I know I can make:

```
"some string".replaceAll("some regex", "new value");
```

But i would like something like:

```
"some string".replaceAll("some regex", new SomeThinkIDontKnow() {
    public String handle(String group) {
        return "my super dynamic string group " + group;
    }
});
```

Maybe there is a Java way to do this but i am not aware of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how such a replacement can be implemented.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExCustomReplacementExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(
      new ReplaceFunction() {
        public String handle(String group)
        {
          return "«"+group.substring(1, group.length()-1)+"»";
        }
      }.replace("A simple *test* string", "\\*.*?\\*"));
  }
}
abstract class ReplaceFunction
{
  public String replace(String source, String regex)
  {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(source);
    boolean result = m.find();
    if(result) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.length());
        int p=0;
        do {
          sb.append(source, p, m.start());
          sb.append(handle(m.group()));
          p=m.end();
        } while (m.find());
        sb.append(source, p, source.length());
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return source;
  }
  public abstract String handle(String group);
}
```

Might look a bit complicated at the first time but that doesn’t matter as you need it only once. The subclasses implementing the `handle` method look simpler. An alternative is to pass the `Matcher` instead of the match `String` (group 0) to the `handle` method as it offers access to all groups matched by the pattern (*if* the pattern created groups).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Java regex API directly.

Create a [`Pattern` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for your regex (this is reusable), then call the `matcher()` method to run it against your string.

You can then call `find()` repeatedly to loop through each match in your string, and assemble a replacement string as you like.